# Why do I get "Generic Failure" error while sending SMS?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am working on android project where I need to send **SMS**. My app collects required information by **consuming a web service** and this information is **very short and pure text.** This information is then sent in the form of SMS.

I have used **broadcast receiver** that will keep track of whether SMS is sent successfully or not and simply add a log entry. I have used **SmsManager** to **send SMS**.

My device is having very good WiFi strength and good GPRS network. While sending SMS, I have found that broadcast receiver inserts log entries, some for "Successful" and some for "Generic Failure".

Why few SMS fail because of "Generic Failure"? What is the reason behind this?

I have googled and found that some people are saying to turn OFF WiFi. But for consuming web service I need WiFi ON.

Can anyone give some insight on this? Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you are sending a lot sms together it will flood your phone so it is preferable to have some delay.

Next if you do delay you have to see to that it is not done in the UI thread or else you will get ANR.

Try using handlers, my friend suggested this, I tried and it works fine.

As for Generic issue, I am not sure.. The name Generic makes it sound like it could be a normal network error.

Hope this information is useful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its true, I was sending a lot SMS together. So I changed this n now sending one SMS at a time which reduces number of **Generic Failure** error to minimum, almost nil. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I had already to overcome this generic failure message with the help of time delay to send one device to multiple numbers, It almost remove the generic failure

```
for(int index=0; index < phone.length; index++){
             phonenumber=phone[index];
            Toast.makeText(cxt, "Phone number is: "+phonenumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(index==0){
                Send_SMS(phonenumber.toString().trim(), textmessage);
            }
            else{
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Send_SMS(phonenumber.toString().trim(), textmessage);
                    }
                }, 1000*40);
            }
        }

public void Send_SMS(String phonenumber, String message){

    // here you use sms manager to send the sms
}
```

Comment: Yeah Sunil, I did the same. I used some delay between two consecutive message sent method call and then it worked fine.

Comment: okk thanks @kavitaDev is it fine to delay 40 sec or need more ?

Comment: I have specified a delay of 20 sec and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

add this permissions in your AndroidManifest file

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Comment: I had already added required permissions. There must be something else which causes Generic Failure. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: not adding this will cause SecurityException not Generic_Failure

Answer (score 0):

I have met similar problem. After couple of minutes, I found the phone number I try to send is invalid.

Thus, any one has this problem, please check the phone number first!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out I was out of my credit balance in my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I found that once the data is over 160 chars, i got a generic failure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by removing the sim phone from `sendTextMessage` and made it `null`