# SmsManager failed to send sms with error RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE, with Vodafone, Airtel Sim cards

Tags: android, telephony, smsmanager

I am trying to send SMS using method sendTextMessage(), of android.telephony.SmsManager . For Vodafone and Airtel sim cards, registered BroadcastReceiver receives the error "RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE", on trying to send SMS. For Idea and Docomo sim cards the code is working perfect. 
O.S. of the device is 5.1.1, but not a version specific, also occurring on other devices too.
I am sending only 1 SMS at a time and no bulk SMS.
I have already checked this link "[Sending sms error Generic failure again and agian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36477226/sending-sms-error-generic-failure-again-and-agian)", and tried with the answers there, still no luck. Can anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have got the reason behind this. I was setting destination mobile number for sms in the following format:

for eg. 91XXXXXXXXXX for Indian Mobile number
This was accepted by and working for Idea and Docomo sim cards.

For Vodafone and Airtel, it started working when I added prefix "+" to the above format. So, the format is:
+
for eg. +91XXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Did this fix this issue for all users? I got about 70% failed SMS-sending (rest succeeded), almost all because of this error. I hope this one will fix it...